# How do I check spinner is empty?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I need to check if mine spinner is empty. But when there's a data inside of spinner, it's still showing me toast it's empty, does not contain any data. The main problem is that the spinner is already containing data from database,but program keeps adding new data after again app open.

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getApplicationContext());


    if (spinner.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Spinner will be populated now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.insertData();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Spinners is already populated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    loadData();
}

public void loadData(){
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String label = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),"Selected: "+label,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```

Database

```
public databaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_2 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_3 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_4 + " TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, "1");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, "2");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_4, "3");
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

public List<String> getAllLabels() {
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(2));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(3));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return labels;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do time consuming works like calling db from main application thread. call db asynchronously for example use `AsyncTask`.

you can get spinner items count like this:

```
int count = spinner.getAdapter() != null ? spinner.getAdapter().getCount() : 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for a tip,but i've never used before AsyncTask,so i will have to learn this. For now,i just want to make everything work,there's no problem if app will be must take a while to "calculate" the instructions. It's just a dummy version of app. In final version,it will be replaced with better code. I've puted your string into Main Activity,but the result is still same - spinner still downloading data from db.

Comment: @Muszy1 sure when onCreate is called spinner is just created and it is empty just like it is created for first time.

Comment: @Muszy1 if you want to reuse fetched arrayList , you have to put it in a bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` and reuse it in `onCreate`. as you can see `onCreate` has an argoument of bundle type this bundle may contains saved states but for first run this bundle is null. you should check that bundle not to be null then get back what you have saved in it. you can save to that in `onSaveInstanceState` which also has a bundle argument.

Answer (score 0):

I've been checked your code and always is calling db.insertData() because the spinner getCount at beginning always is 0.

So I let you some changes that I made in your MainActivity and also I created a method in Database class to know when I need to populate the db or not.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener{
    private Spinner spinner;
    private Database db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            db  = new Database(getApplicationContext());

            if(db.shouldPopulate()){
                db.insertData();
            }

            loadData();
        }

    public void loadData(){
        List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String label = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),"Selected: "+label,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
}
```

**Database**
Here I changed the condition of the result in the insertData method for the result of the insertion.

And I created a method to know when you should insert the data.

```
public boolean insertData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, "1");
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, "2");
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_4, "3");

        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) != -1;
    }

    public boolean shouldPopulate(){
        return  getAllLabels().isEmpty();
    }
```

I hope this code helps you.

**IMPORTANT**

You should wrap your db calls in a background handler, this is very important in Android apps for performance and as good practices.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you adding data to your spinner? You just declare it:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

You should use Adapter to add data to your Spinner:

```
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And what  `spinner.getCount()` means? May be it must refers to the `adapter`?